# Assign color to values

Tags: julia

Let's say I have code that generates me a 2D array with values 0,1,2 or 3. E.g.

```
x = rand(Int8.(0:3), (4,4))
```

and now I want to plot that on a 2D grid whereas we assign each value a color, e.g.:

0: white, 1: green, 2: blue, 3: red

Example:

Assume I have the matrix

```
0 3
2 1
```

then I'd like to have the following image:

[image]

now I thought I could use heatmap but the following code

```
using Plots
data = [0 3; 2 1]
heatmap(data, c=cgrad([:white, :green, :blue, :red], categorical=true))
```

gives me
[image]

As you can see, it "plots" the values of the matrix along the axis. The axis imply an ordering of my data and thus my image gets flipped and rotated.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write e.g.

```
using Plots
heatmap(x, c=cgrad([:white, :green, :blue, :red], categorical=true))
```

if you want to disable axis and legend and reverse the rows write (using matrix operations):

```
heatmap(reverse(x, dims=1),
        c=cgrad([:white, :green, :blue, :red], categorical=true),
        axis=nothing, legend=:none)
```

or using `heatmap` kwarg (I retain the axis to show that they are flipped)

```
heatmap(x, yflip=true, c=cgrad([:white, :green, :blue, :red], categorical=true))
```

Comment: Heatmap doesn't work since it orders my data. I basically want to interpret my matrix as an image. The grid is fixed by the matrix. No ordering of data, no axis with any kind of ordering. Just a grid.

Comment: I do not understand your comment - could you please clarify? I assume you want to have no axis and no legend after your update.

Comment: normally the origin is in the bottom left and axis go right and up. I have shown two options how to change it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to have any implicit ordering. An axis is growing, starts at 0 and grows to some value e.g. x=1,2,3,4,5. So if I make a heatmap with my matrix, it get's orientated such that it fits the axis. That's not what I want. I just want a grid. :) Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I present a solution with [Gaston.jl](https://github.com/mbaz/Gaston.jl), which uses gnuplot as a backend.

A common way to solve a problem like this using gnuplot is to define a custom palette and plot the matrix as an image. Gaston sets up the axes so that the matrix "looks" the same mathematically and as an image; in other words, element `[1,1]` is drawn on the left top corner; the element on the last row and last column is drawn on the bottom right corner.

So, this works (at first sight):

```
using Gaston
M = [0 3; 2 1]
pal = "defined (0 'white', 1 'green', 2 'blue', 3 'red')"
imagesc(M, Axes(palette = pal, colorbox = :off, tics = :off))
```

[image]

A difficulty with this approach is that gnuplot scales both the arrray elements and the palette to the range `[0,1]`. So, the extremes of the palette are always assigned to the minimum and maximum elements of the array. So, the following example fails:

```
M = [1 0; 0 1];
pal = "defined (0 'white', 1 'green', 2 'blue', 3 'red')"
imagesc(M, Axes(palette = pal, colorbox = :off, tics = :off))
```

[image]

We would like to see two green squares instead of two red ones.

A possible solution is to programatically generate a palette that works. Assuming that we know in advance the range of (integer) elements of the array and the palette, the following function calculates a custom gnuplot palette that fits the matrix being plotted:

```
const colors = Dict(0 => "white", 1 => "green", 2 => "blue", 3 => "red")

function define_pal(M)
    entries = unique(M) |> sort
    pal = "defined ("

    for e in entries
        pal *= "$e '$(colors[e])'"
        if e == entries[end]
            pal *= ")"
        else
            pal *= ", "
        end
    end
    return pal
end
```

Two examples:

```
M = [1 0; 0 1];
imagesc(M, Axes(palette=define_pal(M), colorbox=:off, tics=:off))
```

[image]

and

```
M = [1 3; 3 1];
imagesc(M, Axes(palette=define_pal(M), colorbox=:off, tics=:off))
```

[image]

Note that Gaston requires having gnuplot installed.

Comment: Procduces wrong result for M = [1 0; 0 1], again: Having a coordinate system isn't required. It introduces problems. :)

Comment: The problem is not the coordinate system: gnuplot maps both the elements of `M` and the provided palette to the range `[0,1]`, so that the maximum value of `M` is always assigned the last color in the palette. I don't see any way to work around this in gnuplot; however, it might be possible to programatically create a palette adjusted to the min and max values in `M`.

Comment: @xotix Please see my expanded answer.

Comment: That's a nice solution. I tried everything in this thread and it seems that the solution of Bogumil actually works too and I just did something wrong when trying it yesterday. Since i'ts using the native implementation I'll go with it. Sad I can't accept both.